# Using jQuery to animate SVG color and scale on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have an icon that I made, and am trying to both change the color on hover, and have the white square scale 50% via origin top-left of it's current location.

So far I'm able to change the color and the scale of the square on hover in/out, but I can't wrap my head around animating it. Any help, friends?

[My CodePen](http://cdpn.io/tcenz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added this `css3 transition`, to set the transition time for the scaling and background changing:

```
.logo-square, .logo-bg{
  transition: 0.7s;
}
```

And using this `jQuery` to scale the box: (since you are using jQuery. ***Note: You can do this in pure CSS using :hover selector***)

```
$('.logo-square').css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(0.6)',
    '-moz-transform': 'scale(0.6)',
    '-o-transform': 'scale(0.6)'
});
```

and (to revert back)

```
$('.logo-square').css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(1)',
    '-moz-transform': 'scale(1)',
    '-o-transform': 'scale(1)'
});
```

using `.css` instead of `.attr()`

**[SAMPLE DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sDFtu)**

UPDATE: **You can use pure CSS to solve the problem, using the `:hover` selector**

like this:

```
.logo-square, .logo-bg{
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.bm-logo:hover > .logo-square{
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
    -o-transform: scale(0.6);
}

.bm-logo:hover > .logo-bg, .bm-logo:hover > .logo-square{
  fill: #b565a7; 
}
```

**[SAMPLE DEMO - USING PURE CSS](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Afhdx)**

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm still beginning with jQuery and would have never thought of that. And I was able to do all except scale using the hover selector in CSS. For some reason I just couldn't do it, so I then decided to use jQuery.